# Powershell Convert new files to tiff

Tags: powershell, autorun, ghostscript

I have a powershell script that I frankensteined together that looks at a folder for newly added files, then moves those files to another folder that then gets converted using ghostscript to a .tif. After that all .pdf's get moved to a PDF folder and all tiffs get moved to a TIF folder. When complete it makes a log entry to a txt file. Any new files that get dropped into the Import folder trigger this script to run again.

The issues I'm having:

1. The converted Tiffs have "TIF" in front of the file name, I do not want that, just the same name as the pdf it was created from.
2. When a second file is converted it creates a copy of the last converted file and sticks it in the root folder. Not sure why that is. But I only want one copy of the tif, and it to be put in the TIF folder.

Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Code:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
   $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Folder\Import"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 

    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\Folder\log.txt" -value $logline

                    #Path to your Ghostscript EXE
                $tool = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe'
                    #Directory containing the PDF files that will be converted
                $inputDir       = 'C:\Folder\'
                    #.pdf Files
                $pdfDir         = 'C:\Folder\*.pdf'
                    #.tif Files
                $tifDir         = 'C:\Folder\*.tif'
                    #Directory catchall for all incoming files.
                $dumpDir        = 'C:\Folder\Import\*.*'
                    #Output path where converted PDF files will be stored
                $pdfOutputDir   = 'C:\Folder\PDF'
                    #Output path where the TIF files will be saved
                $tifOutputDir   = 'C:\Folder\TIF'

Get-ChildItem -Path $dumpDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $inputDir
$pdfs = get-childitem $inputDir -recurse | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{
    $tif = $tifOutputDir + $pdf.BaseName + ".tif"
    if(test-path $tif)
    {
        "tif file already exists " + $tif
    }
    else        
    {   
        'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
        $param = "-sOutputFile=$tif"
        & $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
    }
Get-ChildItem -Path $pdfDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $pdfOutputDir
Get-ChildItem -Path $tifDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $tifOutputDir   
}

              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for the question/answer edit.

Here is the working script. It has quite a few changes but performs how it needs to. Mid development I was asked to change from .pdf to .tiff to .txt to .jpg. The process still works quite well you just have to modify the Ghost script portion to get the output type desired.

Lots of help from other threads so quite a bit of this script has been Frankensteined together from a plethora of different people.

**Needed components:**

1. Powershell
2. CutePDF Writer
3. GhostScript

**Run down of what this script does:**

1. Scans folder and logs files
2. Moves .txt files to root folder for processing
3. Prints .txt files to .pdf using CutePDF Writer
4. Converts .pdf files to .jpg using Ghostscript
5. Moves .pdf, .jpg, and .txt files to individual folders
6. Deletes all .pdf
7. Starts change scan on "Processing" folder if change is found runs script again.

I converted this to an .exe and used NSSM to set it as a service to always run.

```
$freshStart = 0
$PrintPageHandler ={
param([object]$sender, [System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs]$ev)

$linesPerPage = 0
$yPos = 0
$count = 0
$leftMargin = $ev.MarginBounds.Left
$topMargin = $ev.MarginBounds.Top
$line = $null

$printFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font "Arial", 10

# Calculate the number of lines per page.
$linesPerPage = $ev.MarginBounds.Height / $printFont.GetHeight($ev.Graphics)

# Print each line of the file.
while ($count -lt $linesPerPage -and (($line = $streamToPrint.ReadLine()) -ne $null))
{
$yPos = $topMargin + ($count * $printFont.GetHeight($ev.Graphics))
$ev.Graphics.DrawString($line, $printFont, [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black, $leftMargin, $yPos, (New-Object System.Drawing.StringFormat))
$count++
}

# If more lines exist, print another page.
if ($line -ne $null) 
{
$ev.HasMorePages = $true
}
else
{
$ev.HasMorePages = $false
}
}
While ($freshStart -eq 0)
{
$prossDir        = 'C:\FINAL\PROCESSING\'
$files = get-childitem -Path $prossDir | where {$_.Extension -match "txt"}
foreach($file in $files)
{
$path = "C:\FINAL\PROCESSING\$file"
$logline = "$(Get-Date), BackLog, FINAL, $path"
Add-content "C:\LOG\log.txt" -value $logline
}
#Path to your Ghostscript EXE
$tool = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe'
#Directory containing the PDF files that will be converted
$inputDir       = 'C:\FINAL\'
#.pdf Files
$pdfDir         = 'C:\FINAL\*.pdf'
#.jpg Files
$jpgDir         = 'C:\FINAL\*.jpg'
#.txt Files
$txtDir         = 'C:\FINAL\*.txt'
#Directory that deletes all old pdfs
$deleteME       = 'C:\FINAL\DELETE\*.pdf'
#Directory catchall for all incoming files.
$dumpDir        = 'C:\FINAL\PROCESSING\*.*'
#Output path where converted PDF files will be stored
$pdfOutputDir   = 'C:\FINAL\DELETE'
#Output path where the JPG files will be saved
$jpgOutputDir   = 'C:\FINAL\Folder2'
#Output path where the TXT files will be saved
$txtOutputDir   = 'C:\FINAL\Folder1'

Get-ChildItem -Path $dumpDir -File | Move-Item -Destination $inputDir


function Out-Pdf
{
param($InputDocument, $OutputFolder)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$doc = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
$doc.DocumentName = $InputDocument.FullName
$doc.PrinterSettings = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
$doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = 'CutePDF Writer'
$doc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = $true

$streamToPrint = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $InputDocument.FullName

$doc.add_PrintPage($PrintPageHandler)

$doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "$($InputDocument.DirectoryName)\$($InputDocument.BaseName).pdf"
$doc.Print()

$streamToPrint.Close()
}

Get-Childitem -Path "C:\FINAL" -File -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object { Out-Pdf $_ $_.Directory }


$pdfs = get-childitem $inputDir | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{
$jpg = $inputDir + $pdf.BaseName + ".jpg"
$cJpg = $inputDir + $pdf.BaseName + "_" + "%03d" + ".jpg"
if(test-path $jpg)
{
"jpg file already exists " + $jpg
}
else        
{   
'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
$param = "-sOutputFile=$cJpg"
& $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
}  
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $pdfDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $pdfOutputDir
Get-ChildItem -Path $jpgDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $jpgOutputDir
Get-ChildItem -Path $txtDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $txtOutputDir
Remove-Item -Path $deleteME

$freshStart = 1
}


### SET Folder TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SubFolder YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\FINAL\PROCESSING"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = 
{
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, FINAL, $path"
Add-content "C:\LOG\log.txt" -value $logline
#Path to your Ghostscript EXE
$tool = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe'
#Directory containing the PDF files that will be converted
$inputDir       = 'C:\FINAL\'
#.pdf Files
$pdfDir         = 'C:\FINAL\*.pdf'
#.jpg Files
$jpgDir         = 'C:\FINAL\*.jpg'
#.txt Files
$txtDir         = 'C:\FINAL\*.txt'
#Directory that deletes all old pdfs
$deleteME       = 'C:\FINAL\DELETE\*.pdf'
#Directory catchall for all incoming files.
$dumpDir        = 'C:\FINAL\PROCESSING\*.*'
#Output path where converted PDF files will be stored
$pdfOutputDir   = 'C:\FINAL\DELETE'
#Output path where the JPG files will be saved
$jpgOutputDir   = 'C:\FINAL\Folder2'
#Output path where the TXT files will be saved
$txtOutputDir   = 'C:\FINAL\Folder1'

Get-ChildItem -Path $dumpDir -File | Move-Item -Destination $inputDir

$PrintPageHandler ={
param([object]$sender, [System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs]$ev)

$linesPerPage = 0
$yPos = 0
$count = 0
$leftMargin = $ev.MarginBounds.Left
$topMargin = $ev.MarginBounds.Top
$line = $null

$printFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font "Arial", 10

# Calculate the number of lines per page.
$linesPerPage = $ev.MarginBounds.Height / $printFont.GetHeight($ev.Graphics)

# Print each line of the file.
while ($count -lt $linesPerPage -and (($line = $streamToPrint.ReadLine()) -ne $null))
{
$yPos = $topMargin + ($count * $printFont.GetHeight($ev.Graphics))
$ev.Graphics.DrawString($line, $printFont, [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black, $leftMargin, $yPos, (New-Object System.Drawing.StringFormat))
$count++
}

# If more lines exist, print another page.
if ($line -ne $null) 
{
$ev.HasMorePages = $true
}
else
{
$ev.HasMorePages = $false
}
}
function Out-Pdf
{
param($InputDocument, $OutputFolder)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$doc = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
$doc.DocumentName = $InputDocument.FullName
$doc.PrinterSettings = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
$doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = 'CutePDF Writer'
$doc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = $true

$streamToPrint = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $InputDocument.FullName

$doc.add_PrintPage($PrintPageHandler)

$doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "$($InputDocument.DirectoryName)\$($InputDocument.BaseName).pdf"
$doc.Print()

$streamToPrint.Close()
}

Get-Childitem -Path "C:\FINAL" -File -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object { Out-Pdf $_ $_.Directory }


$pdfs = get-childitem $inputDir | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{
$jpg = $inputDir + $pdf.BaseName + ".jpg"
$cJpg = $inputDir + $pdf.BaseName + "_" + "%03d" + ".jpg"
if(test-path $jpg)
{
"jpg file already exists " + $jpg
}
else        
{   
'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
$param = "-sOutputFile=$cJpg"
& $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
}  
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $pdfDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $pdfOutputDir
Get-ChildItem -Path $jpgDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $jpgOutputDir
Get-ChildItem -Path $txtDir -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $txtOutputDir
Remove-Item -Path $deleteME
}    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```